# How to Angular Insert Data Input to MongoDB with PHP Codeigniter

Tags: angular, mongodb, codeigniter, insert

I'am start to using Angular Framework, MongoDB and Codeigniter. I want to ask that Angular basic Input form the filed are Name: Email: Address:. I want that the three filed Data insert into MongoDB. The Data not direct go to MongoDB, first the data Transfer to PHP Codeigniter and the field Name and Then go to Database(MongoDB). I already using Nodejs.

please Tell me What is the actually Angular Data transfer code or data Insert Code.

---

### branch-list.component.ts

```
      name: {
        title: 'Branch-Name',
        width: '40%'
      },
       Address: {
        title: 'Address',
        width: '40%'
      },
    }
  };

  constructor(private router: Router, private generalApiService: GeneralApiService
    , private route: ActivatedRoute, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.generalApiService.getAll(this.apiUrl).subscribe(res => {
      this.branch = res;
    });
  }
---------------------------------------------------------------
pages.module.ts
---------------------------------------------------------------
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages-routing.module';
import { ThemeModule } from '../@theme/theme.module';
import { MiscellaneousModule } from './miscellaneous/miscellaneous.module';
import { ModalComponent } from './components/modal.component';

const PAGES_COMPONENTS = [
  PagesComponent,
  ModalComponent
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    DashboardModule,
    MiscellaneousModule,

  ],
  entryComponents:[
    ModalComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    `...PAGES_COMPONENTS,`
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
`mongo_db.php in CI
---------------------------------------------------------------------
$config['mongo_db']['active'] = 'default';

$config['mongo_db']['default']['no_auth'] = true;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['port'] = '27017';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['username'] = '';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['password'] = '';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['database'] = 'myancon';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['db_debug'] = true;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['return_as'] = 'array';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['write_concerns'] = (int) 1;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['journal'] = true;
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_preference'] = 'primary';
$config['mongo_db']['default']['read_concern'] = 'local'; //'local', 'majority' or 'linearizable'
$config['mongo_db']['default']['legacy_support'] = false;

------------------------------------------------------------------
branch.php Controller in CI
-------------------------------------------------------------------
class Branches extends REST_Controller
{
  public function index_post() {
        if ($this->input->method(TRUE) === 'POST') {
            $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            $data = array(
                "branchname" => $this->input->post('branchname')
                ,"address" => $this->input->post('address')
                ,"phone" => $this->input->post('phone')
        );

            if ($this->input->post('_id') != null) {
                $_id = $this->input->post("_id");

            } else {
                $this->Branch_model->add($data);
            }

            $this->response([], 201);
        }
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------
Branch_model.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------
class Branch_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function add($data) {
        return $this->`mongo`_db->insert("branch", $data);
    }
}
```

Angular Data connection code and Data Insert Code pls explain with Angular file name!

`

Comment: Difficult to understand what you're asking. Are you asking at which point in the code the insert is performed to the database? Try to rephrase your question

Comment: It seems that you need help with using APIs from CodeIgniter in Angular. This may help you - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7r_UtWUV-_I